# Printing PDF in jsp in iframe contents

Tags: jsp, pdf, printing, apache-fop

I have researched several options for printing a pdf inside an iframe and none seem to be working.

Simple Details:

1. I get some search parameters from a user.
2. I do a database search and then use Apachi FOP to generate a PDF of the results.
3. They are directed to a webpage that has a print and cancel button.
4. When the user clicks the Print button, it will open a window displaying the PDF.
5. A print dialog will open up for the user to print the PDF.
6. The PDF file is deleted from the server.
7. The windows close

Advanced Details:

- This only needs to work on IE8.
- The FOP integration does not use any XSLT translations. It only uses a StringReader of the inputted FOP XML formatted as a string
- The window displaying the PDF is actually two JSP pages.
- The first page:

  - Has an iframe with the second JSP page as a source
  - Runs a printPDF() function on load that prints the PDF in the iframe
- The second page:
- Uses Java BufferedOutputStream and ServletOutputStream

  - Will delete the file after outputting
  - Uses out = pageContent.pushBody();

Here is part of the first jsp page (the run that calls the print function):

```
<body onload='printPDF()'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="content">
            <%
            // get myfilename from the myfile parameter on the URL
            String myfile = request.getParameter("myfile");
            out.print("<iframe src='fc_view_letter.jsp?myfile="+ myfile + "' id='pdfFrame'></iframe>");
            %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    function printPDF()
    {
        var id = 'pdfFrame';
        var iframe = document.frames ? document.frames[0] : document.getElementById(id);
        var ifWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;

        ifWin.focus();
        ifWin.printPage();
        //ifWin.print();
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Here is most of the second JSP Page (the one that shows the pdf):

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.URLDecoder" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%
String myfile = request.getParameter("myfile");
String myfiledecoded = "";
myfiledecoded = URLDecoder.decode(myfile, "UTF8");
String myfilename = myfiledecoded;
String extension;
int dotPos = myfilename.lastIndexOf(".")+1;
extension = myfilename.substring(dotPos);
int slashPos = myfilename.lastIndexOf("/")+1;
String secondparam = "filename=" + myfiledecoded.substring(slashPos);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", secondparam);
try {
        ServletOutputStream sout = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", secondparam);

        File  file  = new File(myfilename);
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);

        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fstream);


        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(sout);

        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        while(-1 != (bytesRead = bis.read(buff, 0, buff.length))) {
             bos.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
        }

         bis.close();
         bos.close();

         sout.flush();
         sout.close();

         //file.delete();

}
catch (Exception e)  {    
 System.out.println("Exception Occured...................." );
}
   out.clear();
    out = pageContext.pushBody();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

What I think is the issue:
I'm thinking that the buffer eliminates all of the html and only displays the PDF. Or at least it does that in IE. When I looked in Firefox it embedded the PDF file. Maybe I cannot grab the contents of the iframe because it is no longer HTML.

Here are my sources so far:

[Javascript Print iframe contents only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616426/javascript-print-iframe-contents-only)

[How to open print dialog after pdf generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733276/how-to-open-print-dialog-after-pdf-generated)

http://www.ehow.com/how_7352227_use-javascript-print-pdf.html

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/4086.htm

[how to print pdf inside embed/iframe using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494243/how-to-print-pdf-inside-embed-iframe-using-javascript)

[Printing contents of a dynamically created iframe from parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831147/printing-contents-of-a-dynamically-created-iframe-from-parent-window)

Comment: I would be willing to add a onload print event to the FOP XML if anybody knows how to add javascript events to FOP XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was generating the PDF then using iText I added some print JavaScript that ran when the PDF loaded